# Generate table based on aggregate values in R

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame in the following format and I want to get table based on aggregate value:

```
VALUE   Time1   Time2
   1    NN  NF
   2    FF  FF
   7    NF  FF
   4    NN  NN
   3    NN  FF
   3    NF  NF
   5    NF  NF
   6    FF  FF
```

I can create a simple table by using the *table()* function

```
 table(Time1,Time2)
```

Which gives me the  following output

```
     FF FN  NF  NN  Total
 FF  2  0   0   0    2
 FN  0  0   0   0    0
 NF  1  0   2   0    3

Total 3 0   2   0    5
```

I want the above data frame to be cross tabulated based on the sum of the ***VALUE*** column. I can do that in excel using the *sumif* function and get the following output.

```
    FF  FN  NF  NN  Total
 FF 8   0   0   0   8
 FN 0   0   0   0   0
 NF 7   0   8   0   15
 NN 3   0   1   4   8
 Total  18  0   9   4   31
```

I need help to do this in R ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cases of `sum` you can just use `xtabs`. Here, I've wrapped it in `addmargins` to get the totals too:

```
addmargins(xtabs(VALUE ~ Time1 + Time2, mydf))
#      Time2
# Time1 FF NF NN Sum
#   FF   8  0  0   8
#   NF   7  8  0  15
#   NN   3  1  4   8
#   Sum 18  9  4  31
```

---

More generally, you might want to look at `dcast` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, Time1 ~ Time2, value.var="VALUE", fun.aggregate=sum, margins=TRUE)
#   Time1 FF NF NN (all)
# 1    FF  8  0  0     8
# 2    NF  7  8  0    15
# 3    NN  3  1  4     8
# 4 (all) 18  9  4    31
```

---

To address @SimonO101's question, if the data are correctly factored, then all levels will show by default with the `xtabs` approach. However, you will need to specify `drop = FALSE` with the `dcast` version.

Taking the above data (which, as it is does not contain a "Time1" or "Time2" of "FN"), let's `factor` both those columns and see how that changes the output:

```
mydf[-1] <- lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) factor(x, c("FF", "FN", "NF", "NN")))
addmargins(xtabs(VALUE ~ Time1 + Time2, mydf))
#      Time2
# Time1 FF FN NF NN Sum
#   FF   8  0  0  0   8
#   FN   0  0  0  0   0
#   NF   7  0  8  0  15
#   NN   3  0  1  4   8
#   Sum 18  0  9  4  31
```

As mentioned, the `dcast` equivalent would be:

```
dcast(mydf, Time1 ~ Time2, value.var="VALUE", 
      fun.aggregate=sum, margins=TRUE, drop=FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 But, why is the un-used `FN` level dropped. I read that by default it should exist?

Comment: @SimonO101, because their sample data is not reproducible. If "Time1" and "Time2" were properly factored, it would be there.