# How not to drop factor levels in R cross tabulated tables?

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data frame in the following format and I want to get cross tabulation table:

```
 T1   T2
 NN  NF
 FF  FF
 NF  FF
 NN  NN
 NN  FF
 NF  NF
 NF  NF
 FF  FF
```

I can create a simple cross tabulation table by using the table() function

table(T1,T2)
Which gives me the following output:

```
   FF FN  NF  NN
FF  2  0   0   0 
FN  0  0   0   0 
NF  1  0   2   0
```

However the factor level NN  is dropped by default. Is there a way I can retain the NN level in the table. Which will table output look like:

```
   FF FN  NF  NN
FF  2  0   0   0 
FN  0  0   0   0 
NF  1  0   2   0
NN  0  0   0   0
```

edit:

```
  dput(dataframe) gives: 

   structure(list(T1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("FF", 
   "NF", "NN"), class = "factor"), T2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
   3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FF", "NF", "NN"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("T1", 
   "T2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show us `dput(head(.))` of your data frame.

Comment: What is the `class(T1)` and `class(T2)`? I think `table` does not drop levels unless `exclude` is specified.

Comment: @BlueMagister, i have added dput() in the edits

Comment: @musically_ut the class(T1) and class(T2) are 'factor'

Comment: Note that you have a typo: The dropped level isn't "NN", it's "FN".

Comment: How is this question warranted after [this answer I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19959202/1270695)? You read the last part of my answer too, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I used the dcast(drop= FALSE ) as suggested by you and it worked for the aggregation based cross tabulation but I couldn't get it to work for simple cross tabulation. I am sure there is way to do that but in reshape2 but I was back to using table() for simple cross tabulation therefore this question.

Comment: @Arihant, in my answer, I had written "if the data are correctly factored, then all levels will show by default with the xtabs approach". `xtabs` is a type of `table`, and the same general approach could have been used to create the proper factors (`dataframe[] <- lapply(dataframe, function(x) factor(x, c("FF", "FN", "NF", "NN"))); table(dataframe)`). Note that with this approach, you *do not* need to worry about the order (unless you want to specify the order in which the columns/rows should appear).

Comment: @AnandaMahto,this explanation helps a lot. factors and levels make much more sense now. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "FN" isn't listed in your input data.  You can get around this by calling `levels()` and informing R that it *is* one of your levels, it just is a level that does not have any observations in your dataset.  For example,

```
dframe <- read.table(text=" T1   T2
 NN  NF
 FF  FF
 NF  FF
 NN  NN
 NN  FF
 NF  NF
 NF  NF
 FF  FF", header=T)

levels(dframe$T1) <- c("FF", "NF", "NN", "FN")
levels(dframe$T2) <- c("FF", "NF", "NN", "FN")
with(dframe, table(T1,T2))
    T2
T1   FF NF NN FN
  FF  2  0  0  0
  NF  1  2  0  0
  NN  1  1  1  0
  FN  0  0  0  0
```

One special note: you are overwriting the original levels here, so you need to put the new, nonexistent, level *last*, otherwise R will call your "NF" level "FN" and lead to all sorts of problems.

Comment: thanks! this is not the first time levels have got me into trouble.

Comment: You're welcome, @Arihant; they're tricky. Be careful of the "special note" I added at the end. You may want to call `levels(T1)` (etc.) *first* before changing the levels so that you can visually inspect them & make sure you haven't inadvertently changed something you didn't mean to.